# Load data from redshift using spark-redshift in Java

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, amazon-redshift

I am trying to load data from redshift in spark using spark-redshift in java.

```
//DataFrame iplocation = sqlContext.read().schema(customSchema).json(jsonFile.getFile().getPath());
         DataFrame iplocation = sqlContext.read()
                    .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")
                    .option("url", "jdbc:redshift://test.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/spay?user=&password=")
                    .option("query", "select * from test.iplocation")
                    .option("tempdir", "s3n://test/")
                    .load();
```

POM dependecies added

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
    <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
    <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.databricks/spark-redshift_2.10 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-redshift_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I am getting the following error

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at com.databricks.spark.redshift.JDBCWrapper.registerDriver(RedshiftJDBCWrapper.scala:59)
            at com.databricks.spark.redshift.RedshiftRelation.schema(RedshiftRelation.scala:56)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.LogicalRelation.<init>(LogicalRelation.scala:37)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:125)
            at com.samsung.cloud.mopay.trsanalytics.test.etl.spark.TestSparkPostToken.testSpark(TestSparkPostToken.java:69)
```

Am I missing any dependencies here?
Does spark-redshift support java?
Am I using a wrong version here ?

Comment: Are you actually using version 0.6.0 of `spark-redshift`? The line numbers in your stacktrace seem to correspond to the 0.5.0 release: https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/blob/v0.5.0/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/redshift/RedshiftJDBCWrapper.scala#L59

Comment: @JoshRosen . Thanks for pointing out. I had two versions in my pom.xml. ITs resolved now.